# converging sequence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

Is the following true?
'If a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ defined in a bounded closed region converges to a continuous function $f$ as n approaches infinity, then $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$.' If it is, how can I prove it? If it isn't, is there any counterexample?

Comment: Consider functions on $[0,1]$ which are zero expect for a peak at $1/n$ of height $1$. They converge pointwise to $0$ but not uniformly.

Comment: They are not continuous functions.

Comment: See my answer for a clarification of Jochen's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Munkres book on Topology. Your statement is true if $f_n$ is additionally a monotone increasing sequence. But in general it doesn't have to be true.

---

The following is a counterexample to your statement. Define

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx, x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}] \\
1-n(x-\frac{1}{n}), x \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}] \\
0, [\frac{2}{n},1]  \end{cases}$$

$f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and converges pointwise to the zero-function, but not uniformly.

Comment: @SC2020 This is an "if", not an "only if".

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks. I corrected that.

Comment: I understood your counterexample. What do you mean by '$f_n$ is an increasing sequence'?

Comment: @Sphere $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$

Comment: Is the proof of 'is true if $f_n$ is additionally a monotone increasing sequence' in the Munkres book?

Comment: I think it is given as an exercise in the book. So the proof is not provided but it is easy to find one. Just look for a partial converse of the uniform limit theorem. It also has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912999/prob-10-a-sec-26-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-partial-converse-to-the-u).