# Partial Converse of Uniform Limit Theorem from Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Here is the question given in the book *Topology* written by James R. Munkres.

> Prove the following partial converse of the uniform limit theorem: *Let $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous
> functions, with $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for each $x \in X$. If $f$ is
> continuous, and if the sequence $f_n$ is monotone increasing, and if
> $X$ is compact, then the convergence is uniform.*

I found several solutions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279862/prob-10-sec-26-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-how-to-give-examples-of-this-result) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912999/prob-10-a-sec-26-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-partial-converse-to-the-u). I also tried to solve this question by myself, by using the Extreme Value Theorem (despite it is introduced in the next section), and want to check whether my attempt is correct or not.

Here is my attempt:

> Define a sequence of functions $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by $g_n(x) = f(x) - f_n(x)$ for $x \in X$. Then $g_n(x) \to g \equiv 0$ for each $x \in X$. To show that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, it suffices to show that
> $$
> \sup \;\{ g_n(x) \mid x \in X\} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty. 
> $$
> Since $X$ is compact, $g_n$ attains its maximum $M_n$ by the Extreme Value Theorem, that is,
> $$
> \sup \; \{ g_n(x) \mid x \in X \} = M_n.
> $$ Since $(f_n)$ is monotonic increasing, $(g_n)$ decreases monotonically, and so the sequence $(M_n)$. Moreover, by the convergence and monotonicity of $(f_n)$, we have $g_n(x) \geq 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in X$, and so $M_n \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n$. Hence by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence $(M_n)$ converges to some point $\alpha \geq 0$.
> If $\alpha>0$, then $(g_n)$ cannot converge to $g \equiv 0$ by the definition of $(M_n)$, and so $\alpha = 0$. Therefore $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

Any comment or criticism is welcomed.

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me.

Comment: @jasnee That’s a relief! Thanks a lot :)